# Getting 'ImportError: cannot import name ' when I run it using Django

Tags: python, django, jupyter

I am new to Django and trying to execute a simple "hello world" program.

I created urls.py file and trying to import views. When I run manage.py I get:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from django.views (C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\views__init__.py)

How can I resolve this?

Exception in thread django-main-thread:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\XYZ\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\XYZ\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "c:\users\XYZ\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\dj_XYZ\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('',include('calc.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "c:\users\XYZ\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\dj_XYZ\mysite\calc\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.views import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'django.views' (C:\Users\XYZ\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\views\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the wrong module. At least that's what I've experienced. Could it be that you have the "wkhtmltopdf" package? If so, it has no module named "view". To fix that, uninstall it, and then install "django-wkhtmltopdf". Link: https://pypi.org/project/django-wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 0):

In the file "*C:\dj_XYZ\mysite\mysite\urls.py*" you are importing a module that doesn't exist:

```
from django.views import views  # django.views.views doesn't exists!
```

Maybe you want to import the views of "calc" app?
In that case you should do:

```
from . import views
```